# Rendering HD video in Java Swing? Too slow?

Tags: java, swing, video, video-streaming

I would like to enable HD video playback for my Java Swing application but I am concerned about scalability and apparent lack of direct screen write access. I have a native C++ library which will do encoding and decoding (h.264) I will access this library through JNI and it will return an int[] that I will render to the screen.

Encode/decode performance is pretty good thus far through JNI. I am concerned, however, about the rendering overhead. I would like to have multiple renderings of video open at the same time so I would like to ensure that I'm doing things in the most efficient way possible.

Is this the most efficient way of rendering video with Java/Swing? Is there any way I can write directly to the screen and not have to go through the Java paint system?

This is how my code looks:
`
public class VideoDisplay extends JLabel {

```
BufferedImage m_bufferedImage = null;


public VideoDisplay(Dimension frameSize) {
    // If there is nothing to show, make sure the widget is black.
    setBackground(Color.black);

    m_bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(frameSize.width, frameSize.height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    ImageIcon frameIcon = new ImageIcon(m_bufferedImage);
    setIcon(frameIcon );

}

public void displayNewFrame(int[] newPixels, Dimension imageSize) {
    m_bufferedImage.setRGB(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height,
            newPixels, 0, imageSize.width);
    repaint();

}
```

}`

Right now my overhead for displaying 720p video at 24FPS seems to be about 6% of CPU on a Core2 Quad 6600 CPU.

Is there any faster way of doing this?

Comment: Have a look at JMF (Java Media Framework): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework

Comment: Java Media Framework is ancient and hasn't been updated in ages. It doesn't support many formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bypass Java completely and either use a surface, or put the data in a direct buffer and a volatile image back this.

Edit: doesn't look like you might be able to do the latter easily. Anyway, transfer the image data through JNI via a direct byte buffer. You can get a buffer pointer in C.

Answer (score 2):

The DJ Native Swing project has a win32 media player and VLC player which can be embedded in Swing: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns